# Missing App After Downloading

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, ios-appstore

I've downloaded Tumblr on to my iPad 2 and the button in the App Store now shows OPEN.

[image: App Store]

But when I tap the 'OPEN' button, nothing appears (it's just the same!)

[image: OPEN button selected]

I checked it again after resetting the home screen view so it's arranged. I searched for 'T' and there's no Tumblr!

[image: Home screen]

Maybe it's bit blurry, but there's all the apps which started with T. I've searched in the search Spotlight too but also, nothing appears with 'Tumblr'.

Comment: Reboot your device

Answer (score 3):

Reboot the device by holding both the power and home button until the Apple logo is shown. This will reset the SpringBoard cache which should show the app on the home screen if it's been downloaded (and in Spotlight).

Comment: IT. Have you tried turning it off and on again?